# Cooking safety and cricket flour

Tags: baking, food-safety, flour

I'm looking into starting to cook with cricket flour as a way to easily consume protein on the go. I'm currently considering various options such a smoothies, muffins and/or granola bars. However, I was wondering:

1. How should I store my cricket flour?
2. Does cooking baked goods with cricket flour mean I have to refigerate them?
3. How long can I store baked goods in a sealed container at room temperature if baked with cricket flour?

Contrasting the answers to these questions with comparisons to regular flour would be appreciated to get a sense of the differences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Probably like any other dry good, in a cool dark room temeperature, sealed container.  Since it is dessicated, it should be essentially shelf stable.   You might get a longer shelf life in the freezer, but that should not be necessary.  In any case, you should follow the manufacturer instructions.
2. That depends on the item, and how much moisture it has.   Very dry cracker like items no.  Very moist items, certainly.  In between, you probably have a day to two days, just like any other baked good.
3. According to one [Thailand based manufacturer](http://www.thailandunique.com/cricket-flour-protein-powder) (breeder?  farmer?)  the shelf life is two years.  They do not indicate refrigeration is required.